# Alternative for Complex Firestore Queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore, subquery

I created a mobile application with React Native and Firebase however I'm facing limitations with Firestore when I want to do a complex query on multiples fields. For example, here I want to request only the first 100 persons based on some conditions.

```
const ref =  firestore().collection('people')
    .where("gender", "==", this.state.currentUser.genderPreferred)
    .where('age', '>=', this.state.currentUser.minimumAgePreferred)
    .where('age', '<=', this.state.currentUser.maximumAgePreferred)
    .where('longitude', '<=', this.state.currentUser.longitude) // Example here, Haversine function...
    // Potentially more conditions...
    .orderBy('timeStamp')
    .limit(100)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        let listUsers: User[] = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            listUsers.push({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            });
    });
```

But it is not possible to do it with Firebase...

A temporary workaround that I'm using right now is to do the filtering on the client side however, it is not possible as data tends to be big.

*In the Firestore documentation, they say about the limitations but they don't suggest any alternatives* so I was wondering if you have some good suggestions for NoSQL Database which are very easy to scale and **convenient** to do POST / GET request (with nothing to set up server side, just like Firebase in fact...).

I was thinking about ElasticSearch and deploy it on GCP (in order to have only one cloud provider - Google - for Firebase and ElasticSeach) but if you have better ideas that would be really nice.

Thank you,

Comment: All NoSQL is generally the same. And when you get to off-the-shelf serverless NoSQL (Firestore, AWS AppSync, etc), the similarities are even stronger. The NoSQL limitations you encounter with a flagship platform like Firestore will generally be the same with other providers. To most efficiently perform complex queries, like yours, really requires a custom server. Which means you have to get clever with Firestore. But if you want to talk about efficiency, your geoquerying is highly inefficient and that, IMO, is a bigger hole to fill than what you're asking about.

Comment: For instance, you can build a very powerful geoquerying mechanism using NoSQL that doesn't require a greater-than/less-than operator. And for filtering users by age, if you want to talk efficiency, you should be querying on birthday and not an age field that you would have to update every 24 hours.

Comment: Oh I understand why they ask birthday instead of age now... Well in my head, I'm still 20 so... Thank you for the answer, actually the geoquery here is just an example but there are still limitations (and it is said in the Firestore documentation) for example, it is impossible to do something like:

`citiesRef.where('population', '>', 2500000).orderBy('country');`

I've read some workaround like combining index in the same field but I don't think that's feng shui and easily maintanable / scalable that's why I prefer to look for a technology which is better suited for that type of query.